# Alert user when they open a preselected app

Tags: java, android

I'm relatively new to Android development and am trying to display a prompt to the user whenever they navigate away from the app and try to run a different pre-selected app. I'm aware that I can't detect the start up but I believe I can view the active app with the following:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

for (int i = 0; i < runningAppProcessInfo.size(); i++) {
  if(runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName.equals("com.the.app.you.are.looking.for" && disabled == true) {
    // Display overlaying message to users!
  }
}
```

1st question: How can I get this code to be checked many times a second like in a polling event? Would I use an Async Task or a Background Service and how would I communicate with it to update the `disabled` boolean?

2nd question: Should the message I display to the user be a SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW or something else so as to overlay all active apps?

Comment: As an aside: unless you've got a _very_ good reason for doing so, that you've not explained in the question, throwing up a dialog when I tried to run a different app would almost certainly lead to your app being instantly uninstalled!

Comment: On modern android versions there is no way for you to detect which app is in the foreground while yours isn't. Try your code snippet on anything running Lollipop or higher and see for yourself. [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int))

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a sticky background service that checks this every second if you want to. Then you can use the System Alert Window or you could always launch your own Activity with new Task flag and make the activity transparent, do your popup or toast, then close yourself.